# Effective type of temporary object in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, type-punning

This is a question related to [defect report 452](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_452) of the C standard. Document [N1888](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1888.pdf) provides further information about the original problem, but I cannot understand why it states the following:

> The effective type rule from 6.5.p6 (the rule that describes what is the effective type of an object) does not seem to apply to an object with temporary lifetime resulting from a comma expression. As such, it does not seem to have an effective type. **As such, type punning is seemingly allowed**:
>
> ```
> long func3() {
>    union u2 o3 = { .x=42 };
>    return (0, o3).y;
> }
> ```

My question is what causes type punning to be legal if the object with temporary lifetime created by the expression `(0, o3)` does not have an effective type? I believe the effective type of that object would be relevant only if one would try to access its stored value using a different type, but I do not see how that is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the effective type of that object would be relevant only if one would try to access its stored value using a different type, but I do not see how that is the case here.

But indeed the object is tried *to access its stored value using a different type*.

```
union u2 {
    int x;
    long y;
    char ca[2];
  };
```

Members `x` and `y` have different types (even if they might have the same representation).

> But when it comes to unions one cannot say we are accessing one object through the type of the other (I know there is some debate about this, but there is a note in the standard that allows type punning through unions; I know notes are not normative, but I believe the intention was to make it valid).

It appears you are referring to this *note in the standard*:

95. If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
    store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
    as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
    punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

You'd need to define what you mean by *valid*, but according to the above, it cannot mean "guaranteed behavior as defined by the standard", since it could lead to a "trap representation", i. e. undefined behavior if read.

Comment: From the point of view of the Standard, I don't think the values of non-lvalue expressions are stored anywhere, and as such I don't think they're "accessed".  Certainly for types like `unsigned`, it would seem weird to say that, during the evaluation of `w=x*y+x*z;` the value `x*y` is "read" from somewhere, especially since an implementation might not even bother to compute that value at all, instead computing `x*(y+z)` [unsigned arithmetic behaves as an algebraic ring, so such transformations are legitimate].

Comment: The only really weird situation that arises is when a value of structure or union type contains an array.  I think the Standard should have defined the behavior of `[]` on arrays contained within non-lvalue values of struct or union types, but forbidden such arrays from decaying, but doing that now would be a breaking change.

Comment: @Armali Thank you for your response. But when it comes to unions one cannot say we are accessing one object through the type of the other (I know there is some debate about this, but there is a note in the standard that allows type punning through unions; I know notes are not normative, but I believe the intention was to make it valid).

Comment: I thought more about this and I also talked to somebody else and the reasoning for is the one stated by @supercat. If one has, for example, a struct with the first member having an array type, and a function `f` which returns objects of this type, then writing something like `&f().arr[0]` (where `arr` is the struct member with array type) allows us to get the address of an "object with temporary lifetime" (the struct object). And until that defect report such objects did not have an effective type, therefore they could be accessed with no matter what other type.

Comment: @user42768: A lot of confusion could have been avoided if the Standard had recognized that `a[b]` is only equivalent to `*(a+b)` in cases where the operands are a pointer and integer (in either order), and applying `[]` to a value or lvalue of array type yields either a value or lvalue of the element type which identifies the corresponding element of that array, or an empty lvalue "just past" the array.  That would have eliminated confusion about what register-qualified arrays should mean, and also made it possible for implementations to support bitfield arrays when doing so would be useful.

Comment: @user42768: Looking at the defect reports, I think it's clear that there is nothing resembling a consensus about what the "Effective Type" gibberish is supposed to mean.  There has never been any *general* permission to alias an object of structure or union using a pointer or lvalue of member type.  Quality implementations will of course recognize cases where a pointer or lvalue of member type is visibly freshly derived from one of structure type, but that doesn't imply any obligation to expect aliasing when there is no evidence of such derivation.

Comment: @supercat I don't think that making f().arr[0] return an rvalue would solve this problem in particular, as one could get a pointer inside the object with temporary lifetime using f().arr, in a context where that expression would be converted to a pointer to the first element, such as g(f().arr);.

Comment: @supercat Another question of mine was whether the following is legal: struct s { int i; int arr[1]; }; struct s f(); ... *(float*)(&f().i) = 0;. By reading the standard literally, I cannot determine whether the object referred to by f().i now has an effective type or not.

Comment: @user42768: Array lvalues decompose to addresses, but that doesn't mean that rvalues would need to do likewise.  Presently, nearly all situations where arrays in rvalues would decompose fit two patterns: (1) the array is the left operand of `[]`, or (2) code needs to form a temporary object with a certain lifetime, and is using array decomposition as a kludge to do something that should be supported via better means.

Comment: @supercat I agree, but I believe that the current state of the C standard does not differentiate between lvalue or rvalue array expressions when it comes to "decomposition", no?

Comment: @user42768: The C Standard is incredibly sloppy with its terminology.  Any definition of a term X will partition the universe into three kinds of things: those that are definitely X, those that are definitely not X, and those which could plausibly be viewed as either X or not X.  A good definition will seek to reduce the size of the third category.  How effectively does "object--region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values" partition things into those that are definitely objects and those that definitely aren't?

Comment: @user42768: If the C Standard were to start by solidly defining some core concepts, a lot of things could be defined clearly and unambiguously in terms of those concepts while allowing most useful optimizations, but it would make many phony "optimizations" unjustifiable.